# NodeJS, Express, and ejs; why does the test fail, but the view works?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, ejs

I'm working through a PluralSight course/project on NodeJs and Express. They have a project template with tests. The app is working, it is actually finding and rendering the view. But the test for setting the views directory is failing. I have tried many variations of directories for the views, with and without the '/' after the '/views'; I have tried many variations of using the `path.join(__dirname, './src/views')` as well. Nothing seems to satisfy the test, even when I tried using the same values in the test, as in `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../src/views'))` Nothing seems to satisfy the test.

The tests are run with `npm run test:module1`. When that runs there is a line in the console:  `mocha --exit './test/module1/*.spec.js'` The test is definitely finding the app because it runs 8 tests; 7 pass and only this one fails.

But I'm trying to re-learn modern JS, as well as Express and ejs, so I may be missing something basic.

Here's my app.js code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Index'});
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('PS Project Running on port 3000!');
});
```

and here's their relevant test:

```
const path = require('path');

describe('View engine and directory', () => {
  it('should set view engine and directory @app-set-views-directory-engine', () => {
    assert(typeof app === 'function', '`app` const has not been created in `app.js`.');
    assert(app.settings['view engine'] === 'ejs', 'The view engine has not been set to `ejs`.');
    assert(app.settings.views === path.join(__dirname, '../../src/views'), 'The view directory has not been set to the `views` directory.');    
  });
});
```

Comment: Critically missing information: _how does this test run_? Because it's almost certain that `app` simply doesn't exist in your test's scope, but without you telling folks what's actually running that test code, there's literally no way for anyone to tell whether it's there or not. Please explain what the test setup is (mocha? jest? something custom?), how you run it, and what the actual output is.

Comment: I added info on the tests. There is a 'mocha' in the console when it runs. The tests are definitely finding app because it runs 8 tests, 7 pass and only this one fails.

Comment: fails how? What does it actually say? (your post is still missing that information) Also, without a dir layout it's very hard to say whether your relative locations are wrong, so at this point it feels like the first course of action is to contact the person who made the course for PluralSight to let them know their course material has problems so they can (immediately) help you and (long term) fix the course. Just getting an answer yourself on SO does not seem the approach that helps everyone, here.